# Change and animate background image dynamacally using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have following code.

```
    (function ($) {

        var i = 0;

        var header_banner = $(".destination-banner");
        var banners = ["bg1.png","bg2.png","bg3.png"];//<?php  //echo $slide_banners; ?>;

        header_banner.css('backgroundImage', 'url(<?php echo site_url(); ?>contents/images/home-slider/'+banners[0]+')');

        window.setInterval(function () {
            i = i == banners.length ? 0 : i;
            header_banner.animate({backgroundImage: 'url(<?php echo site_url(); ?>contents/images/home-slider/'+banners[i]+')'}, 3000);
            i++;
        }, 30);

    })(jQuery);
```

I was trying to animate background image of the `div.destination-banner` using `animate()` method. I can change background color using same method. But background images. Need to use `ajax` ?

Thanks.

**Edited :**

Pelase find my [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/L1zjrzvc/1/).

Comment: do you want to fade in and out between those images? can you prepare a quick jsFiddle with your content to play around with?

Comment: what is the effect you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: I try to add fade in out effect. I have added jsfiddle.

Comment: did you mean to change every 30ms, or every 30 secs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use ajax to accomplish what you need. The reason for this is that ajax is really all about calling the server for data and then reloading this data, without having to reload the page.

If you really want to use jQuery animate for this, the steps involved is to: 
1) animate the background image to be opacity: 0 2) then set the background-image to the new image and then 3) animate it back in like detailed below in this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   (function ($) {

    var i = 0;

    var header_banner = $(".destination-banner");
    var banners = ["https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8882/18535493118_ecdcc47918_b.jpg","http://www.fs.fed.us/wildflowers/ethnobotany/images/oils/mountain_monardella_lg.jpg"];

    header_banner.css('backgroundImage', 'url("'+banners[0]+'")');

        window.setInterval(function () {

           i = (i >= banners.length) ? 0 : i;

           //animate it to fade, then do a callback, after animation is done
           header_banner.animate({opacity: 0}, function(){

              //change the background image
              header_banner.css('backgroundImage','url("'+banners[i]+'")');

              //fade back in
              header_banner.animate({opacity: 1}, 3000);
              i++;
           });

        }, 30);
   })(jQuery);
});
```

The reason why your code wasn't working in the first place was 1) you tried to animate backgroundImage, when you can't. your `i = (i == banners.length) ? 0 : i;` made it so that it'd be going to keep increasing and `banners.length` is 1 greater than the array position (and once you got past `banners.length`, you'd end up going on getting undefined), and then you didn't put quotes in the `"url("+banners[i]+")";` section, leading to improperly made url values, you needed to interpolate.

Comment: I have done some modification to your code. Now it's working. Thank you ! :). jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/L1zjrzvc/2/